# How can I monitor process completion and push the status to UI?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

Let's say i have read 10k records from DB into my ArrayList. I want to transform the records and push completion progress status to React UI; say at 10% intervals.

How can i push notification from backend code(Spring Boot in my case) to the front end ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send information to the frontend you could use WebSockets. Take a look at this guide on how to do it with SpringBoot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/.

Answer (score 0):

Usually front-end sends requests to backend for data. If you want bidirectional communication you can use socket.io
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/